# WPF .NET Core Publish as Click one

Tags: .net-core, clickonce

I have developed projects using WPF .NET. I use “Click once”, I found it the most comfortable way when this program has to run on multiple clients and I have to update it sometimes.

I am learning .NET Core and I want to know if there is an equivalent to the “Click once” publish method in .NET Core.

Comment: Microsoft add support for clickonce with dotnetcore 5. See [announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/#clickonce)

Comment: Based on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/issues/9) the click once publishing method should be available in .NET 5 which is the latest version of .NET Core. Is that not available to you or do you still need to use 3.1?

Comment: @AshleyMedway yes.. Now I updating my VS and look for it